# Time-decoupling interactions?

Tags: distributed-computing

Can anyone explain to me what 'time-decoupling' interactions means? I have no idea, and can't find a suitable resource which explains it.

It is taken from the concept of a direct message exchange architecture. The question states there is a need to time-decouple the interactions between two clients.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to give more context here for someone to give you a good answer. Where did you hear about this concept?

Answer (score 1):

If two processes are time-coupled, then one process's execution in time is influenced by how the other process behaves. A typical example is a client process that invokes a method on a server process. If this remote method invocation is implemented such that the client call will not return until the server has actually finished executing the method, then the client and the server are time-coupled. If the server happens to have a problem in the execution of the invoked method and takes a long time to complete it, then the client is stalled during 
that time of execution.

This type of dependency between two processes can be considered a risk and can result in fault propagation throughout your distributed system. Therefore, time-decoupled interactions are often preferred. Going back to the client-server example, the time-decoupled version would be an asynchronous remote method invocation, where the the client does *not* block to wait for a response from the server. In stead, the response from the server is communicated to the client asynchronously when it is available. That way, the client process can continue with its own execution without being coupled to the execution of the server process.

In the context of your question, as far as I can see, this indicates that the processes participating in that particular message exchange architecture interact with each other in an asynchronous fashion and you do not have to worry that the message exchange will stall one process because of another (misbehaving) process.